# Any alternative to --openssl-legacy-provider when working with unsupported envelope routines in nuxtjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nuxt.js

I've generated a nuxtjs project for the first time via this command:

```bash
npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>
```

when running both the npm run start, build, and dev commands I get the following output:

```bash
node:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
                ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:140:10)
    at module.exports (/home/me/dev/code/Javascript/Nuxt/first-nux-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/home/me/dev/code/Javascript/Nuxt/first-nux-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at handleParseError (/home/me/dev/code/Javascript/Nuxt/first-nux-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
    at /home/me/dev/code/Javascript/Nuxt/first-nux-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
    at /home/me/dev/code/Javascript/Nuxt/first-nux-app/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
    at /home/me/dev/code/Javascript/Nuxt/first-nux-app/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/me/dev/code/Javascript/Nuxt/first-nux-app/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at Array.<anonymous> (/home/me/dev/code/Javascript/Nuxt/first-nux-app/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:205:4)
    at Storage.finished (/home/me/dev/code/Javascript/Nuxt/first-nux-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:55:16)
    at /home/me/dev/code/Javascript/Nuxt/first-nux-app/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:91:9
    at /home/me/dev/code/Javascript/Nuxt/first-nux-app/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3) {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

What I'm mostly looking at is the `error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported` portion of the error. It seems that when nuxtjs attempts to generate an ssl certificate there's some sort of error in the process. Though I'm not exactly sure.

Is this a common thing with nuxtjs? Or node? Or an issue on my side? I've made a minimal setup of nuxt and I'm getting the same errors (and by minimal I literally just mean hitting enter on every setting)

I'm running this on a minimal setup of arch linux, I've updated node and openssl, so I'm not sure if there's a dependency I don't have.

`--openssl-legacy-provider` is a flag that seems to do the trick, but it feels like putting a band aid over a bullet wound. Using a legacy provider for ssl seems like I'm exposing many vulnerabilities. Is there a better solution?